# The raw and h() in the Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In my rails application I am posting a comment. In rails 3 all data are html safe but in my comment post I want to render only links as html safe. So how can I achieve this partial post as html unsafe and rest as safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across one post related to this. Please have a look at it at http://rorandme.blogspot.in/#!http://rorandme.blogspot.com/2012/03/raw-and-h-in-rails.html. See if it helps.